# WKID issue when adding raster layer from ArcGIS "mapserver" to QGIS via REST

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, arcgis-rest-api, gdal-translate

QGIS docs [here](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Arcgis_rest) describe how to do this. I am trying to add a layer from this MapServer:

```
gps.digimap.gg/arcgis/rest/services/JerseyBaseMap/MapServer
```

When I try the following command from the Python console I get the error below.

```
>>> qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://gps.digimap.gg/arcgis/rest/services/JerseyBaseMap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")
```

[image: popup]

If I instead try the gdal_translate command line option it appears to be a issue with the the Well Known Text ID not being recognised:

```
$ gdal_translate --debug on "http://gps.digimap.gg/arcgis/rest/services/JerseyBaseMap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true" JerseyBaseMapLayer.xml -of WMS
HTTP: Fetch(http://gps.digimap.gg/arcgis/rest/services/JerseyBaseMap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true)
WMS: Did not get WKID
HTTP: Fetch(http://gps.digimap.gg/arcgis/rest/services/JerseyBaseMap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true)
ERROR 4: `/tmp/file.dat' not recognised as a supported file format.

GDALOpen failed - 4
`/tmp/file.dat' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

**Question**: As I know this provider's SRS (EPSG:3109) can I 'tell' QGIS/GDAL to apply it to the source data file, say by pointing to a WKT definition file?

gdal_translate has an option `[-a_srs srs_def]` to overide the *output* file projection, but I can't see a way to apply an SRS to an file imported via the REST API..

Very frustrating, as the data can easily be viewed in the ArcGIS webmap viewer:

www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?basemapUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fdcw7.digimap.gg%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FJBM%2FMapServer&source=sd

Comment: I think this does not work when a TMS/Mapserver with Multiple layers(?)